# How do I access a file through SOQL queries?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I need to find something that is inside a sObject referenced in my SOQL search, but the search just returns the file name. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: You should post this question on the Stackexchange Salesforce Community where you will get a more Salesforce focussed audience.

Comment: Can you provide you SOQL string please?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm.

From this document:

> "ContentDocumentLink represents the link between a Salesforce CRM
>   Content document or Chatter file and where it's shared. A file can be
>   shared with other users, Chatter groups, records, and Salesforce CRM
>   Content libraries. This object is available in versions 21.0 and later
>   for Salesforce CRM Content documents and Chatter files."

Example query:

```
"SELECT ContentDocument.title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId = '069D00000000so2' AND LinkedEntityId = '0D5000000089123'"
```